# CSS3 ::selection selector not working properly on anchor tags

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS3 `::section` Selector like this

```
::selection{
    color:red;
    background-color:pink;

}
::-moz-selection {
    color:red;
    background-color:pink;

}
```

So when some element is selected it should change its color to red and the background to pink.

It works as expected for everything other than the Anchor tag `<a>`.

When an anchor text is selected, it applies the style to the link text but not on the line beneath the anchor text.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GcBT2/1/

So how can we apply the style to the underline also?

PS: Browsers tested: chrome 31 and firefox 25.0.1

Comment: I was going to suggest CSS [`text-decoration-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color) but I was unable to get it to work. I might be doing it wrong though: http://jsfiddle.net/GcBT2/3/

Comment: @OllyHodgson `text-decoration-color` is only supported in firefox at the moment. Check http://jsfiddle.net/GYw7g/. Besides `::selection` does not support this property as stated in the specs.

Comment: @nkmol I tried it in Firefox nightly :)

Comment: @nkmol only in ff and chrome, still won't work for ::selection as you can read from ExtPro's answer.

Comment: text-decoration-color also not working in FF 25

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that [per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection)

> Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used in a rule using
>   ::selection in its selector: color, background, background-color and
>   text-shadow. Note that, in particular, background-image is ignored,
>   like any other property.

The line on your link is part of `text-decoration` which is not taken into consideration by the pseudo selector. Your best bet would perhaps be to remove it using

```
a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

You may want to also note:

> Though this pseudo-element was in drafts of CSS Selectors Level 3, it
>   was removed during the Candidate Recommendation phase ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selection))
>
> The ::selection pseudo-element currently isn't in any CSS module on
>   the standard track. It should not be used in production environments.

[Further information](http://www.impressivewebs.com/status-selection-pseudo-element/)

Comment: Thanks for  the answer , you once again proved that often times MDN has better information than the official W3C specifications. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's an old [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35146) on bugzilla which relates to your problem. As you can see in [comment 26](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35146#c26) a selection is actually an extra anonymous element, that's why text-decoration of the surrounding anchor won't change its color since the selector only applies for this "child": `<span>The word <span::selection>select</span::selection> is selected</span>`.

Comment: Thanks for providing the insights and digging into the Bugzilla :)